# Replacing nested loop with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

In the query below I do calculate the combined value of all football teams within league 1. The solution I've came up with, though it works, seems rather bulky.

I would like to find a better approach i.e. a one lined linq query like so:

```
footballteams.Where(x => x.League == 1).Sum(x => x.Networth);
```

My current code:

```
List<IGrouping<int, FootballTeam>> footballTeams = context.FootballTeam
    .GetQueryable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.TeamName)
    .ToList();

var prem = footballTeams.Where(x => x.League == 1).ToList();
var totalWealth = 0;

foreach (var team in prem)
{
    foreach(var singleteam in team)
    {
         totalWealth = totalWealth + singleteam.networth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why group and then ungroup to get the sum of the `networth`? Wouldn't it make more sense to get the teams as a `List<FootballTeam>`, then from this list you can group or you can sum, whichever you like? Also, how can you run `.Where(x => x.League == 1)` on an `IGrouping`? Those objects don't have a `.League` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it all in a single statement:

```
var totalWorth = context.FootballTeam
    .GetQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.League == 1)
    .GroupBy(x => x.TeamName)
    .Sum(x => x.Sum(y => y.NetWorth));
```

You also skip the enumeration performed by the two `ToList()` calls with this.

Answer (score 11):

Use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) then `Sum`.

```
var totalWealth = footballTeams.Where(x => x.League == 1)
                               .SelectMany(x => x.Select(e => e.networth))
                               .Sum();
```

`SelectMany()` Exceprt:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

Answer (score 4):

```
totalWealth = footballTeams
    .Where(x => x.League == 1)
    .Select(
        x => x.Select(
            y => y.networth
        ).Sum()
    )
    .Sum();
```

If you want you can make it one line, but you will notice that readability is crucial for productive coding.

Comment: this will not compile. Due to the second Select. TO make it compile the first Select should be SelectMany

Comment: @CodeNotFound I think they meant to do `.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.networth).Sum()).Sum();`. With the current example, seems like there is a  typo `y.networth.Sum()` from the author.

Comment: @CodeNotFound with the edit, it should now work. Also, note that  `SelectMany` is only required if you want to collapse nested sequences, the inner `Select` in the answer returns a scalar value so `SelectMany` is not required here. But yes one could also do it with `SelectMany` as in my answer :).

Comment: great . You're right. SelectManay not needed with this version :-)